# How to use - as alias?

Tags: bash, alias

When I was using openSUSE 11.3, it came with several aliases already set up. Two that I used a lot were `+` for `pushd .` and `-` for `popd`. Now on Debian, I can't figure out how to create the second one. `alias -=popd` tries to read `-=` as a command option to alias. I've tried putting quotes (both single and double) around it, and preceding it with a backslash, but I just keep getting error messages. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this:

```
alias -- -=popd
```

worked at least for me:

```
usr@srv % alias -- -=echo
usr@srv % - test
test
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. What does the `--` do, exactly?

Comment: @Wolf: For most commands, `--` marks the end of options; everything after it is arguments. For example, `logger foo -x bar` would log "foo bar" and treat `-x` as an option, while `logger -- foo -x bar` would treat it as an ordinary word in the message "foo -x bar".

Comment: The `--` indicates that no more options follow on the command line, following `-`'s aren't interpreted as options. So this allows you to `cat` files that start with a `-` ;-)

Comment: @grawity and @binfalse: Thanks for the explanation, that's very helpful! Very good to know.

Answer (score 9):

In `bash` you can create functions named as such:

```
+() { pushd "$@"; }
-() { popd "$@"; }
```

Comment: what is `$@`?

Comment: @Lazer: In sh and bash, `$@` expands to all arguments given to the function or script. Unquoted it works the same way as `$*`. When inside double quotes, however, it expands to _exactly_ the same words as originally given, [without any additional splitting.](http://pastie.org/1828726)

Comment: @Lazer: `$@` expands to all the parameters passed to the function (equivalent to `"$1" "$2" ...`). For more information, do `man bash` and search for Special Parameters.